# The problem with running the Simulink model on arduino uno

Tags: matlab, arduino, hardware, simulink

I ran into a problem when running the simulink model. I have an mpu6050 sensor, and also an esc+bldc motor is installed on 9 pins. I have data reception from the mpu and sending a signal to the engine working separately (checked). They also work together. But as soon as I add any block to the model, for example, PID, discrete PID, transfer function (discrete), integrator, etc., then I get an error like in the 1st image. I tried changing the baudrate value, then I get an error, as in image 2. On the third image - log in the simplest case, when all work, on the 4th my model. I don't understand why even adding a transfer function block results in an error.

[image: Error by add PID]

[image]

[image: Normal]

[image: Model]